# Can pandoc convert footnotes from latex to inline-footnotes in markdown?

Tags: footnotes, pandoc

I googled but couldn't find and option or extension to convert a `tex` file to `md` with inline footnotes.

For example, `Topic\footnote{Important topic}` is converted to

```
Topic[^1]

[^1]: Important topic
```

Is there a way to have this as output?

```
Topic^[Important topic]
```

I tried many combination with extensions `footnote` and `inline_notes`, as well as other intermediate document formats, as HTML and docx.

Comment: Footnotes in LaTeX can have multiple paragraphs that are not supported by the inline notes by pandoc,  so converting to this format would produce corrupted documents, while what you obtain  is  not the syntax that you want to see, but it will work no matter the if your note is a single sentence or two paragraphs.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if pandoc has an option but you could convert with a few lines of perl:

**`file.md`**

```
Topic[^1]
Another Topic[^2]


[^1]: Important topic


[^2]: Important topic number two
```

**`fn.pl`**

```
my $values = shift;

open my $fh1, '<', $values;
    
while(<$fh1>) {
    if (/^ *(\[\^[0-9]+\]): *(.*)/) {
       $fn{$1}="$2";
    }
}

open my $fh1, '<', $values;
while(<$fh1>) {
    s/^ *(\[\^[0-9]+\]):.*//;
    s/(\[\^[0-9]+\])/^[$fn{$1}]/go;
    print $_;
}
```

**`perl fn.pl file.md`**

```
Topic^[Important topic]
Another Topic^[Important topic number two]
```

this does one pass, collecting footnotes in a hash, then a second pass replacing the references.

Comment: Great workaround! If pandoc doen`t have such a feature, I think it should be include in the future.

Comment: +1, But  it should be noted what this will work only if there are not any paragraph break in the note.  For instance `Topic\footnote{Important.\par Foo.}` will be exported `Topic^[Important.]`,  leaving  `Foo.` as verbatim monospaced text ... in the main text! In a big document this could cause quite a mess. Moreover, even if you can export this  as `^[Important.` *<paragraph break>* `Foo.]`  the result is still wrong because pandoc actually cannot understand this as a footnote, and therefore will type all of this as main text, including "as is" the `^[` and the `]`.

Comment: @Fran yes it needs one-line footnotes and lacks any error checking or recovery

Comment: @Jander I'm afraid the trend is just the opposite.  Rstudio's new visual mode now automatically "corrects" all inline notes to no inline footnotes. You can choose to move them to after the paragraph or at the end of the text, but not leave them inline using the visual mode. I am aware that Rstudio is not pandoc and is not markdown, but I would say that it is indicative there are some reason/s to avoid the inline notes.